# Get closest date in SQL as a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, closest

I have a requirement in SQL where i have to check from list of dates, the date which is closest to it.
eg: from below data i have to check if for date `" 2020-03-21"`
data:

```
name   date
abc    2020-03-20
abc    2020-03-21
abc    2020-03-23
def    2020-03-22
def    2020-03-24
```

expected:

```
name   date        expected
abc    2020-03-20  2020-03-21
abc    2020-03-21  2020-03-21
abc    2020-03-23  2020-03-21
def    2020-03-22  2020-03-22
def    2020-03-24  2020-03-22
```

Based on earlier posts, using orderby datediff and rownum, I was able to get the rownum in correct order but kind of stuck as in how to get the closest date at name level.

Comment: My bad!
i edited my post.. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a subquery for this:

```
select
    t.*,
    (
        select top 1 t1.date 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.name = t.name
        order by abs(datediff(d, t1.date, '2020-03-21')), t.date
    ) expected
from mytable t
```

The subquery returns the closest available date to the target (either earlier or later) within rows having the same `name`. If there are ties, the "early" date is preferred.